# split dataframe entries at midnight

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a `pandas` `dataframe`, with `Start` and `End` datatime.

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data=pd.date_range('20100201', periods=10, freq='5h3min'),columns=['Start'])
df.loc[:,'End']=df.loc[:,'Start']+pd.Timedelta(4,'h')
```

`Start` and `End` can be expected to be sorted interally, but gaps/overlaps may occur between consecutive rows.

I would like to create a new dataframe with the difference that if row contains midnight (e.g. midnight is contained in [`Start`,`End`]), the row is then split in two parts before and after midnight
ex:

```
 Start                 End
0 2010-02-01 00:00:00 2010-02-01 04:00:00
1 2010-02-01 05:03:00 2010-02-01 09:03:00
2 2010-02-01 10:06:00 2010-02-01 14:06:00
3 2010-02-01 15:09:00 2010-02-01 19:09:00
4 2010-02-01 20:12:00 2010-02-02 00:12:00
5 2010-02-02 01:15:00 2010-02-02 05:15:00
```

should be

```
Start                 End
    0 2010-02-01 00:00:00 2010-02-01 04:00:00
    1 2010-02-01 05:03:00 2010-02-01 09:03:00
    2 2010-02-01 10:06:00 2010-02-01 14:06:00
    3 2010-02-01 15:09:00 2010-02-01 19:09:00
    -----------------------------------------
    4 2010-02-01 20:12:00 2010-02-01 23:59:00
    5 2010-02-02 00:00:00 2010-02-02 00:12:00
    -----------------------------------------
    6 2010-02-02 01:15:00 2010-02-02 05:15:00
```

Comment: what yo mean midnight

Comment: 00:00 basically datetime.min.time()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can concat the DataFrame of new pairs, then erase the old ones.

First find the splits:

```
splits = df[df.End.dt.date > df.Start.dt.date].copy()
```

Now concatenate and drop:

```
>>> pd.concat([
    df,
    pd.DataFrame({
        'Start': list(splits.Start) + list(splits.End.dt.floor(freq='1D')),
        'End': list(splits.Start.dt.ceil(freq='1D')) + list(splits.End)})
]).drop(splits.index).sort_values(by='Start')
    End Start
0   2010-02-01 04:00:00 2010-02-01 00:00:00
1   2010-02-01 09:03:00 2010-02-01 05:03:00
2   2010-02-01 14:06:00 2010-02-01 10:06:00
3   2010-02-01 19:09:00 2010-02-01 15:09:00
0   2010-02-02 00:00:00 2010-02-01 20:12:00
2   2010-02-02 00:12:00 2010-02-02 00:00:00
5   2010-02-02 05:15:00 2010-02-02 01:15:00
6   2010-02-02 10:18:00 2010-02-02 06:18:00
7   2010-02-02 15:21:00 2010-02-02 11:21:00
8   2010-02-02 20:24:00 2010-02-02 16:24:00
1   2010-02-03 00:00:00 2010-02-02 21:27:00
3   2010-02-03 01:27:00 2010-02-03 00:00:00
```

Comment: Consider setting column order with DataFrame's `columns=['Start', 'End']` and resetting index at end. Also, we are missing the one second different endpoint for 23:59:59.

Comment: @Parfait Thanks for the comments - I'll edit it when I'm back by a computer.

Comment: I like it. How does it scale up when nrows is huge, and time resolution is high

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the above answer works when a midnight time occurs early in the list. Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe anytime you drop the indexes of the "splits" it is then dropping too much from the original list then as well.

I recognize this isn't answering the above question, but I don't have the reputation to comment above. In my case, I believe I will likely just convert to a numpy array, insert rows where the midnight points are, and then copy data accordingly. Ugly, but should work.

Comment: how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).