# Splitting DataFrame Entries at Midnight

Tags: python, pandas

I've recently read through this post, but I believe that it breaks down when the split happens early on in the list, such as in the first entry. Moreso, when the index of the splits is less than the size of the split list that is concatenated. I can't comment yet, so I figured I'd pose a question. My end goal really is to just be able to put all this data into day bins, but since the start to end spans day lines then I believe I need them split.

Old answer: [split dataframe entries at midnight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50336251/split-dataframe-entries-at-midnight/50336535#50336535?newreg=382a42ed953f49d8bb1856dd5707b538)

My data:

```
                   AOS                 LOS Duration
0  2024-04-21 17:45:00 2024-04-22 04:00:00    37779
1  2024-04-22 04:00:00 2024-04-22 09:30:00  19800.0
2  2024-04-22 09:30:00 2024-04-22 17:00:00  27000.0
3  2024-04-22 17:00:00 2024-04-23 03:30:00  37800.0
```

Anticipated output:

```
                   AOS                 LOS Duration
0  2024-04-21 17:45:00 2024-04-22 00:00:00    22500
1  2024-04-22 00:00:00 2024-04-22 04:00:00  14400
2  2024-04-22 04:00:00 2024-04-22 09:30:00  19800
3  2024-04-22 09:30:00 2024-04-22 17:00:00  27000
4  2024-04-22 17:00:00 2024-04-23 00:00:00  25200
4  2024-04-23 00:00:00 2024-04-23 03:30:00  12600
5  2024-04-23 03:30:00 2024-04-23 04:00:00   1800
```

Comment: Hey, awesome having you here on stackoverflow! Although you have not yet earned the priviledge of commenting on a post you should be able to add an answer (ie scroll down to the bottom of the question and post your solution in the "your answer" textfield).

Comment: Thanks! I went ahead and did that, although really it's moreso that the question wasn't fully answered. Hopefully either there or here the community can come up with a fancy solution. It's definitely possible from just converting to an array and throwing some for loops around.